# Unable to extend desktop. External monitor on powersave mode

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

My Dell e6400 no longer can extend desktop. The external monitor detected and I can changed the resolution in display properties. But the external monitor reported on a power save mode. To confirm this, I unplugged the cable and the external monitor shown 'no signal detected' message.

Tried with many cables and monitors/projectors.

EDIT: Yes, i did enabled second display. I did this using Windows Mobility Center.

Comment: Did you enable extending desktop to the second display?

Comment: Please specify the Os you're on and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Same issue, with perhaps slightly different details